# Photon Cloud in Actionscript Mobile Project get Java compilation Error

Tags: java, iphone, flash, flash-builder, photon

I have a mini-game build in Flash Builder 4.7 with adobe air 3.7 on Mac OSX Moutain Lion
Using Photon-Flash_v3-2-0-1-Beta_Cloud_SDK.zip http://doc.exitgames.com/photon-cloud/SDKflash/
Compiles perfectly in:
 
 * android device (2.3 +)
 * android simulator
 * ios simulator (iOS sdk 6)
 * air simulator

When try compile my game in iPhone (3GS iOS 6.1.3), i got this error:

> Could be a problem with the java version installed? Or bug in sdk
>   flash photon cloud?

Error occurred while packaging the application:

```
AOT Compilation has failed while optimizing null exitgames.common:Logger::format0.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.sccp_eval(GlobalOptimizer.java:7054)
    at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.sccp_analyze(GlobalOptimizer.java:6019)
    at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.sccp(GlobalOptimizer.java:4733)
    at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.optimize(GlobalOptimizer.java:3615)
    at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.optimize(GlobalOptimizer.java:2309)
    at adobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.optimizeABCs(LLVMEmitter.java:532)
    at adobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.generateBitcode(LLVMEmitter.java:341)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.AOTCompiler.convertAbcToLlvmBitcodeImpl(AOTCompiler.java:611)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.BitcodeGenerator.main(BitcodeGenerator.java:104)
Compilation failed while executing : ADT
```

[image: print]

Comment: I'm having the same issue (I think) when I'm trying to use this CharBoost ANE (https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Chartboost) Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Please send us an email to developer at exitgames.com. We have changed the code that causes the issue. It needs verification.

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like adobe optimizer bug which fails on slightly complicated (but still correct!) flash code of the 'format0' method. We will try to refactor this method to something simpler for the optimizer.